# PHP .htaccess files can be reached as directory! How to disable?

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, vps

I have files in my server like `test.php`, `demo.php`, which I can access on my server as `example.com/demo/` or `example.com/demo`. How can I disable it? It overlaps my `.htaccess`.

Comment: *"It overlaps my htaccess"* - what does this mean? Please show your .htaccess file.

Comment: I mean, my htaccess doesnt work  because this problem. if i delete htaccess i can still reach files as directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `multiviews` are enabled on your server. You can disable them using the following line in your htaccess file:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: Thanks man finally :) i am searching since weeks for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a .htaccess file in that directory it self with content

```
Options -Indexes
```

Put this .htaccess file in your demo directory.

Comment: what is the filename you are using.

Comment: demo.php and test.php and my .htaccess file

Comment: Can you paste your site configuration file in your question.

Comment: Do you mean the apache conf ?

Comment: The site configuration file in site-available.

Comment: @user5903926 it is not a good idea to paste your site server configuration file(s) on to the open internet. I'm not sure why answerjunaid thinks this data would be helpful.